# Dynamically create dictionary keys where I can append additional values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I'll be adding data to that looks like this:

```
mydict = {
    'key1': ['First string message', 'Second string message'],
    'key2': ['String message']
}
```

I am iterating through a json object that has two keys - `key` and `message`. I want to add every `key` into `mydict` and append all `message`s that have the same `key`.

Example:

```
[
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'First string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key2',
        'message': 'String message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'Second string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key3',
        'message': 'Brand new string message'
    }
]
```

I am having a problem on building my dictionary dynamically though. How can I dynamically create my keys so that I can append additional strings?

One of the ways I've tried is this:

```
import json
response = [
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'First string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key2',
        'message': 'String message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'Second string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key3',
        'message': 'Brand new string message'
    }
]
mydict = {}
for r in response:
    mydict[r['key']] = mydict.get(r['key'], [r['message']])

print(mydict)
{'key1': ['First string message'], 'key2': ['String message'], 'key3': ['Brand new string message']}
```

This, obviously, fails my expected result because `key1` doesn't contain both strings.

I tried this:

```
for r in response:
    mydict[r['key']] = mydict.get(r['key'], [r['message']]) + r['message']
```

But this fails with `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

How can I dynamically create my keys so that I can append additional strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use either `defaultdict` or `setdefault`. I prefer `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

response = [
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'First string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key2',
        'message': 'String message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key1',
        'message': 'Second string message'
    },
    {
        'key': 'key3',
        'message': 'Brand new string message'
    }
]

mydict = defaultdict(list)

for r in response:
    mydict[r['key']].append(r['message'])
```

With `setdefault` you can make `mydict` a regular dictionary:

```
mydict = {}
for r in response:
    mydict.setdefault(r['key'], []).append(r['message'])
```